# Error in changing threading behavior in ABAQUS

Tags: python, fortran, abaqus

I have written a UMAT code which calls a python code and uses its results. I tried to run the simulation which contains the UMAT code and I got the following error:

Error changing threading behavior: transition to MULTI_THREADED_WINDOWS threading model is not allowed
ImportError: sessionExitCallback module may inly be imported in the Abaqus kernel process
File "SMAPyaModules\SMAPyaAbqPy.m\src_sessionExitCallback.py", line 45, in

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with it.

Comment: Folks will be able to help better if you post the relevant code you wrote. Also, if you think it's the UMAT guys' fault, consider searching on their bug/issue tracker.

Comment: I think it is not related to my code and how I call it since it is running on other computers and not on mine. It might be some problems with the ABAQUS settings on my computer.

Comment: It's not easy to call a Python script from within a UMAT. The issue you are describing might be due to modifying the same file from multiple threads. They can also be due to the fact that when you run Abaqus, all Python environment variables are changed within that environment. I can be more helpful if you give more details into your approach.